# graphicx grid overlay

Tags: graphics, floats

Is there a simple way to get a coordinate grid overlay with a picture incorporated via `\includegraphics`?

I'm using some `\put()` commands for minor annotations, but it'd be nice to not have to guess and do all of it by eye.

The `overpic` package has a `grid` option, but I haven't found an equivalent for `graphicx`? e.g:

```
\begin{overpic}[width=0.5\textwidth, grid, trim=35 100 20 100, clip]{myimage.png}
\put(210, 40){\small $\leftarrow$ An annotation}
\end{overpic}
```

I'd rather not involve an additional package for the sake of one or two figures if I can help it.

Comment: Have you tried the `pagegrid` package? It does not place the grid over the image, but places the grid in page background. Works with `graphicx`. Useful for positioning an image, but not for positioning things inside the image itself.

Comment: I'd not come across that package before, but yeah, that doesn't really fit my needs. Ideally the coordinates will be relative to the image origin rather than the page, since not all images are the same size.

Comment: If you accept tikz, take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/1952. If you don't want to use `TikZ` but accept a packake which loads it, take a look at [`callouts`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359071/1952)